# Mockito - stub abstract parent class method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am seeing very strange behavior trying to stub a method `myMethod(param)` of class `MyClass` that is defined in an abstract parent class `MyAbstractBaseClass`.

When I try to stub (using `doReturn("...").when(MyClassMock).myMethod(...)` etc.) this method fails, different exceptions are thrown under different scenarios. The exceptions are thrown right on that line.

When I use  `doReturn("...").when(MyClassMock).myMethod(CONCRETE PARAM CLASS OBJECT)`, I get the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
String cannot be returned by hasValidExpirationDate()
hasValidExpirationDate() should return boolean
    at ...
```

**`hasValidExpirationDate()` is not a method being stubbed, but it is called by the real implementation of `MyMethod(param)` in the abstract base class.**

When I use  `doReturn("...").when(MyClassMock).myMethod(any(PARAMCLASS.class))`, I get the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
```

, etc.

But when I define the method `myMethod(param)` in a subclass `MyClass` the code no longer fails. My concrete implementation in `MyClass` just calls `super.myMethod(param)` and returns it, so it has no effect other than fixing the unit test. So it looks like Mockito can only stub methods defined in the class being mocked itself, not in the super classes.

I am reading Mockito documentation and I don't see where it says that inherited methods can't be stubbed.

`myMethod(param)` is neither `static` nor `final`.

## Code:

Class `BaseCard`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class BaseCard implements Serializable {

    public boolean hasValidExpirationDate() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Class `Card`:

```
abstract class Card  extends BaseCard {

    public Card () {    }

    public String getUnexpiredStringForNetwork(){

        //If the date is invalid return empty string, except for Discover.
        if( ! hasValidExpirationDate()){
           return "hi";
        }

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Class `DecryptedCard`:

```
public class DecryptedCard extends Card {

}
```

Class `MyTest`:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import org.junit.Test;


public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        DecryptedCard decryptedCardMock = mock(DecryptedCard.class);

        doReturn("ABC").when(decryptedCardMock).getUnexpiredStringForNetwork();

    }

}
```

Failure:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
String cannot be returned by hasValidExpirationDate()
hasValidExpirationDate() should return boolean
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

    at Card.getUnexpiredStringForNetwork(Card.java:10)
    at DecryptedCard.getUnexpiredStringForNetwork(DecryptedCard.java:1)
    at MyTest.test(MyTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: show us the stacktrace

Comment: please edit your question and don't psot it in the comments

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: JB, I am affraid I am not allowed to post my code (I am doing it for work). But maybe I can write some similar code that recreates this problem

Comment: Of course. That's what you should do.

Comment: OK, I edited my question to add the failing code

Comment: The behavior you see is consistent with `getUnexpiredStringForNetwork` being final, because calling it would immediately call `hasValidExpirationDate` (which takes no parameters and returns a boolean like your error message says). Mockito would see that you're starting to stub, see the method call to `hasValidExpirationDate`, and assume that's the method you're stubbing. Since you already checked that it is not final, can you confirm that you are not using Proguard or any other optimization tool that would quietly inline your method calls?

Comment: @JeffBowman I reproduced this in a project of mine not using Proguard or anything like that. This is really strange, and looks like a bug in Mockito to me. I'm using 1.9.5. Overriding the stubbed method in DecryptedCard (by delegating to the super implementation) makes the test pass.

Comment: Jeff, no I am not using Proguard

Comment: I think I know why it happens. The class Card is not public. Mockito probably requires all class in the hierarchy to be public. If I make the class Card public, the problem goes away.

Comment: @VladimirMakhnovsky: are you sure? That's the first thing I tried, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Strange, it does work for me

Comment: There's probably a good answer from these comments...

Comment: I have tried your code here and sucessfully reproduced the error. When using the `public` modifier in the `Card` class the problem goes away here as well. When you change `getUnexpiredStringForNetwork()`'s return type to `boolean` and, of course, change the mocking statement to `doReturn(true)...` the problem vanishes too. Seems like it uses the mocking/return type intended to `getUnexpiredStringForNetwork()` in `hasValidExpirationDate()` **only** if `Card` is not public. I'd file a bug, definitely.

Comment: I do note that at least one Mockito exception refers to [the visibility of the parent class](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/1.9.5/src/org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter.java#L114) causing trouble, and that it's "a limitation of the mock engine". I also encourage Vladimir, JB, or acdcjunior to submit the comment distillation as an answer so others can find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20332391/1426891), mock behavior isn't guaranteed when parent class is non-public, as documented in [issue 212](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=212).

(Thanks Brice for the good answer in the other thread, and thanks Vladimir, JB Nizet, and acdcjunior for sharing debugging progress in the comments thread!)

Answer (score 0):

Wow! That was it!

I was getting strange exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.medziku.motoresponder.logic.ExposedResponder.createSettings(ResponderTest.java:163)
-> at com.medziku.motoresponder.logic.ExposedResponder.createSettings(ResponderTest.java:163)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

While everything was correct. 
I tried to mock method from superclass of mock class, and this superclass was inside same file as mock class, so it was not public and those strange errors arise.
after moving superclass to separate file, and setting it public, problem is gone!