# Mockito - weird package scope class inheritance issue

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Found very interesting issue and after debugging found the scenario to reproduce it.

So, if I have a class with package scope B that has some public method and public class A that extends it:

```
package somepackage;

class B {
   public void someMethod() {
      throw NullPointerException();
   }
}

package somepackage;
public class A extends B {

}
```

and then in the test:

```
A a = mock(A.class);
a.someMethod();
```

and guess what, I am getting NullPointerException that I just threw, so Mockito somehow creates a "real" object and calls a real method instead of mocked one. Why so?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at test.B.setProxy(B.java:6)
    at test.A.setProxy(A.java:1)
    at secretservice.service.TestFDSServiceImpl.testService(TestFDSServiceImpl.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

In the example above I have `IllegalArgumentException` as I changed it in class `B` just to make sure `NullPointerException` is not caused by something else.

Eclipse:  Juno Service Release 1, build id: 20120920-0800
Mockito: 1.8.4 (also tested with 1.9.5)
JUnit: 4.10

Comment: You can check by doing `a.getClass()` or debugging.

Comment: it's class test.A$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$edd8e028 so I assume it just not able to mock the public method from package scope class

Comment: Your mock object is not complete. You should use `when()` to give it some behavior.

Comment: Really? Why it's not complete? To my understanding it should call the dumb mocked method, but it calls a real why. If I do that, this method still will be called... Btw, If I change the scope of B to public, everything works as expected

Comment: Hm. I just tried your example, and it works for me without throwing NPE...

Comment: Ok, cool, so it's fixed. What is your mockito version? Mine is 1.8.4

Comment: I just tried with 1.9.5, I still have the same exception. Btw, did you locate your test in a  different package, I assume? So the B class is not visible to the Test

Comment: Nope, still no problem here. I mean: `B` is not visible to `ATest`, and I don't get a NPE.

Comment: I can reproduce it. Very odd.

Comment: really strange, i updated the question with the exception I have :(

Comment: That's not a NPE, it's an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, in my example I just wanted to make sure that NullPointer is not caused by something else, so I changed it to illegal state, i will update the question now. Btw, did you test with junit or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edit**

Latest mockito 2.x beta use now ByteBuddy which isn't affected by this issue. There may be some API ajustements left but it is pretty much both working and functional. Also there will be breaking compatibility with existing mockito matchers. If that's ok for the project that would be great to have feedback on the API while mockito 2 is in beta.

**original**

There's a known issue when the mocked class have a non public parent. The method cannot be stubbed. See [issue 212](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=212).

> The issue is that bridge methods are generated by the compiler in order to access the method  from the parent, however this confuses bytecode tools like CGLIB. Unless you can fix CGLIB, there's no real solution.

Sorry you have to workaround this in a different way :/

Comment: Thanks for this, yeap, I decided to go for very dumb solution, just creating one more class that inherits from the public class and overrides all not implemented methods, fortunately, in my case they are just setters