# Mockito - stub super (abstract) class method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have DAO code that looks like this:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO <T, I> {
    public I upsert(T entity){
        //implementation
    }
}

public class MyEntityDAO extends GenericDAO <MyEntity, Integer> {
    public List<MyEntity> searchMyEntity(SearchParameters params){
        //domain specific entity search
    }
}

public class MyEntityService{
    private MyEntityDAO myEntityDAO;

    public Integer saveMyEntity(MyEntityVO vo){
        //transform vo to entity with business logic
        return myEntityDAO.upsert(myEntityInstance);
    }        

}
```

I want to test the saveMyEntity() method using Mockito but mockito is showing me an error message - "the method when(t) in the type mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void)".

This is the code:

```
Mockito.when(myEntityDAO.upsert(Matchers.any(MyEntity.class)))
        .thenReturn(1);
```

This is the code that works:

```
Mockito.when(myEntityDAO.searchMyEntity(testSearchParams))
            .thenReturn(mockedListOfMyEntities);
```

It seems that because upsert() is in the superclass of MyEntityDAO and not in MyEntityDAO itself this issue is coming up. Is there any way I can achieve this? Is there any workaround or a different framework that supports this?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the first mockito sample was the one that failed, right?

I tried to copy-paste your code, and created a test of my own, and it seems to work perfectly fine here. Could it be that there is another mock that causes the error? It does complain about a void argument, and your code samples doesn't use void anywhere.

Comment: the message about void argument is coming as an error in eclipse Juno (my JDK version is 8 but set to 1.6 compliance). What IDE are you using?

Comment: The environment I tested on was spring-tool-suite 3.4.0, built on eclipse 4.3.1, with java7, set to java 6. But I don't think this is a version issue.  
The compiler tells us that the Mockito.when()-method cannot accept void as an argument.  
If I change the signature of the upsert method to `void upsert(..)` I get the same compilation error as you do

Comment: Does either class have an overload of `upsert` that returns void?

Comment: Are any of the superclasses of MyEntityDAO non-public? You might be running into [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19915270/1426891).

Comment: the interface between the abstract class and the entity specific DAO class was package level. But fixing that didnt fix the issue.

Comment: Seems like the issue was with the method being updated with void.. had to use Answer to modify the passed object to test the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in the comments:

> Seems like the issue was with the method being updated with void.. had to use Answer to modify the passed object to test the functionality.